# Construct the tree from a list of edges

Tags: python, tree

I was using the following code to construct the tree from a list of nodes: `[1, 2]` means that there is a bi-directional link between `1` and `2`

```
def createTreeFromEdges(edges):
    tree = {}
    for i in edges:
        v1, v2 = i
        if v1 in tree:
            tree[v1].append(v2)
        else:
            tree[v1] = [v2]

        if v2 in tree:
            tree[v2].append(v1)
        else:
            tree[v2] = [v1]

    return tree
```

and it works in the following fashion:

```
edges = [[2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 7]]
print createTreeFromEdges(edges)
```

This is cool, but for a python it looks like too much code. Is there a way to make it shorter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is very Pythonic, but a little too terse if you are not used to it:

```
def createTreeFromEdges(edges):
    tree = {}
    for v1, v2 in edges:
        tree.setdefault(v1, []).append(v2)
        tree.setdefault(v2, []).append(v1)
    return tree
```

Basically, [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) does the following:

```
def setdefault(self, key, default=None):
    if key not in self:
        self[key] = default
    return self[key]
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. The only drawback is that it adds a little bit of overhead. But even when the number of edges is 10000 the time difference is approximately 0.001 sec.

Comment: One of the reasons for `setdefault` to exist is that the C code implementing it does not have to search the dict's hash table twice (one to see if the key exists, another to retrieve the value), but can combine both in a single search. So it should be faster in that respect. Not sure what can be causing the slowdown you are seeing...